# Find diffeomorphism between two sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $\displaystyle A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x,y>0, x^2+y^2>1  \}$ and $\displaystyle B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: 0<y<1  \}$
>
> Find a diffeomorphism $A \to B$ .

I thought maybe it will be helpful to do inversion $f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ on set $A$ then we will get set $A'= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x,y>0, x^2+y^2<1   \}$ but I don't know how to find the diffeomorphism between $A' \to B$

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Are you sure that greater than sign isn't a less than?

Comment: @TylerHg It's greater but after applying inversion f we can consider less then, we can give composition of diffeomorphisms. It come from my classes

Answer (score 0):

First, take a diffeomorphism of $A$ onto $A' = \left\{(x, y):\, x, y > 0\right\}$ given in polar coordinates by $(r, \theta) \to (r, f(r)\theta)$ for some suitable $f$. Then choose a suitable diffeomorphism $g:(0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}^{> 0}$ and extend it to a diffeomorphism $A' \to B$.